# Getting "The IsTestFileByName task failed unexpectedly" error when building my csharp project with sonarqube

Tags: c#, msbuild, sonarqube

Upon building my csharp project with msbuild and sonarqube, i am getting this error.

```
D:\Jenkins\workspace\second-    
project\.sonarqube\bin\targets\SonarQube.Integration.targets(201,5): error 
MSB4018: The "IsTestFileByName" task failed unexpectedly. 
[D:\Jenkins\workspace\second-project\source\Logger\Logger.csproj]
D:\Jenkins\workspace\second- 
project\.sonarqube\bin\targets\SonarQube.Integration.targets(201,5): error 
 MSB4018: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: D:\Jenkins\workspace\second- 
project\3rdparty\sonarqube\msbuild\SonarQube.Analysis.xml 
[D:\Jenkins\workspace\second-project\source\Logger\Logger.csproj]
D:\Jenkins\workspace\second- 
project\.sonarqube\bin\targets\SonarQube.Integration.targets(201,5): error 
  MSB4018:    at SonarScanner.MSBuild.Common.Serializer.LoadModel[T](String 
 fileName) [D:\Jenkins\workspace\second-project\source\Logger\Logger.csproj]
 D:\Jenkins\workspace\second- 
  project\.sonarqube\bin\targets\SonarQube.Integration.targets(201,5): 
  error MSB4018: at 
 SonarScanner.MSBuild.Common.AnalysisProperties.Load(String fileName) 
 [D:\Jenkins\workspace\second-project\source\Logger\Logger.csproj]
D:\Jenkins\workspace\second- 
project\.sonarqube\bin\targets\SonarQube.Integration.targets(201,5): error 
MSB4018: at 

 D:\Jenkins\workspace\second- 
 project\.sonarqube\bin\targets\SonarQube.Integration.targets(201,5): error 
 MSB4018: at SonarScanner.MSBuild.Tasks.IsTestFileByName.Execute() 
  [D:\Jenkins\workspace\second-project\source\Logger\Logger.csproj]
   D:\Jenkins\workspace\second- 
 project\.sonarqube\bin\targets\SonarQube.Integration.targets(201,5): error 
 MSB4018: at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutio nHost.Execute() [D:\Jenkins\workspace\second- 
  project\source\Logger\Logger.csproj]
  D:\Jenkins\workspace\second- 
 project\.sonarqube\bin\targets\SonarQube.Integration.targets(201,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() [D:\Jenkins\workspace\second-project\source\Logger\Logger.csproj]
```

earlier it was running without errors like this. But now, i dont know why, it is giving these errors. Any help ?

***The solution builds well in Visual studio, without sonarqube integration.***

P.S i have tried cleaning and rebuilding the solution.

**Using MSBuild version 15.0**

Comment: Have you solved this? I'm getting the same issue suddenly.

Comment: The exception also suddenly happened here; the reason of the error is in the logr under the line with "Error MSB4018: The "IsTestFileByName" task failed unexpectedly." In my case it was "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: C:\agent\_work...". 
The solution was to make sure the file exists. (strangely it refered to an older version of the task; copying a the file from a newer to the mentioned folder solved it for me.)